# replace attributes values in particular element through jquery

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

i am creating svg chart which contains so many elements like rectangle,path,circle,line etc..
am creating the element by passing json options as well as element where am going to append refer below code.

```
 this.svgLink = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";


drawPath: function (options, element) {
        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "path");
        $(path).attr(options).appendTo(element);

    },

    drawLine: function (options, element) {
        var path = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "line");
        $(path).attr(options);
        $(path).appendTo(element);

    },

    drawCircle: function (options, element) {
        var circle = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "circle");
        $(circle).attr(options).appendTo(element);
    },
    drawEllipse: function (options, element) {
        var ellipse = document.createElementNS(this.svgLink, "ellipse");
        $(ellipse).attr(options).appendTo(element);
    },
```

am passing the options like below code.

```
var rectOptions = {
            'id': this.svgObject.id +'_ZoomArea', 'x': x, 'y': y, 'width': width, 'height': height,
            'fill': 'rgba(69,114,167,0.25)', 'stroke-width': 1, 'stroke':'rgba(69,114,167,0.25)','clip-path': 'url(#' + this.svgObject.id +'_ChartAreaClipRect)'
        };
```

now i want to pass some other options for particular element which was created already instead of creating again just want to replace the attribute values with new values just like $.extend in jquery.

how can i replace the attributes values with new values ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Why can't you use `$(e).attr(rectOptions)`?

Comment: whether it will replace existing attribute values?

Comment: Sure it will. Why do you think it won't?

Comment: am not sure about this.but i need the functionality like $.extend merging two objects same like merging the attributes values.

Comment: It should only overwrite attributes that already exist. Any atrributes that don't already exist will be added. So it will behave like $.extend().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(e).attr(rectOptions)` to overwrite the existing attributes with the new ones.

One thing that worries me a bit, though: You really shouldn't change the `id` option. That might confuse code which has saved the old ID to update the element.

Instead, you may want to use this code:

```
var id = '#' + this.svgObject.id +'_ZoomArea';
var rectOptions = {
            'x': x, 'y': y, 'width': width, 'height': height,
            'fill': 'rgba(69,114,167,0.25)', 'stroke-width': 1, 'stroke':'rgba(69,114,167,0.25)','clip-path': 'url(#' + this.svgObject.id +'_ChartAreaClipRect)'
        };
$(id).attr(rectOptions);
```